# How to find all documents in mongodb using moongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my Query to fetch the doctor collection,

Here is my id array

`var getData = ['123431243124', '13412342314321']`

```
 dbModel.user.find({
        'tags' : {$all:getData }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            if (data == null) {
                res.status(202).json({
                    "success": "0",
                    "message": "User not found"
                });
            } else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                "success": "0",
                "message": err
            });
        }
    });
```

I am getting empty array in the console.

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i get that ?

Comment: can you share the model?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `$in` instead of `$all`

eg.

```
Model.find({'tags' : {$in:getData }}, function(err, data) {
      if(err){
       res.status(200).json({
            "success": "0",
            "message": err
        });
     }else{
         if (data == null) {
            res.status(202).json({
                "success": "0",
                "message": "User not found"
            });
        } else {
            console.log(data)
        }
      }
     });
```

Comment: should we do callback, because i need to return it in a function

Answer (score 0):

```
You must first create the DoctorSchema of your document after that create the model and from your model you can do your query

var doctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({})
var Doctor = mongoose.model("doctor",doctorSchema)

var getData = ['123431243124', '13412342314321']

Doctor.find({tags: {$all: getData }},function(err,datas){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        // use your data here 
    }
})
```